# isControllable and isObservable maple functions: Is there a way to make them show steps?

Tags: math, system, maple

So we can use isObservable to work with some systems but I wonder If we can make tham show staps or do something like that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing that you are actually referring to the `Observable` and `Controllable` commands which are part of the `DynamicSystems` package.

Some Maple routines have so-called `userinfo` messages, which are optionally displayed and which can show partial steps. Those would typically be enabled with a call like `infolevel[DynamicSystems]:=6` where 6 is the highest level of detail. With a lower value less detail might be displayed. Unfortunately, these particular DynamicSystems routines don't seem to have any userinfo messages in them. So this won't help directly in your case.

Sometimes one package calls another. The routine `LinearAlgebra:-Rank` is called, at some point, when `Controllable` is called. I'm guessing that you don't wish to see userinfo messages in `Rank`, which would be enabled by issuing `infolevel[LinearAlgebra]:=n` for some n between 1 and 6.

An alternative is to set `printlevel` high. But doing so will make all Maple internal calls also be verbose. The resulting output of setting, say, `printlevel:=20` is overwhelming. I doubt that you'd find this approach useful.

Another alternative is to set certain routines as option `trace`. Sometimes doing so entails knowing the names of the appropriate internal routines. And this is made more complicated by the fact that not all non-exported module locals are visible by default. You could try first issuing the call, `trace(DynamicSystems::ControllableSS):` before invoking `Controllable` on your system. That shows some intermediary results, but those might not make much sense to you unless you know what source lines are generating those results. You can see the source by issuing the command, `showstat(DynamicSystems::ControllableSS);`

Here's an example,

```
restart:
with( DynamicSystems ):
aSys := StateSpace( <<1,2>|<3,4>>, <<2,3>>, <<1,0>|<0,1>>, <<0,0>> ):
aSys:-a, aSys:-b, aSys:-c:
trace(DynamicSystems::ControllableSS):
Controllable( aSys );
showstat(DynamicSystems::ControllableSS);
```

By looking at the source of the `ControllableSS` routine, you can deduce that it calls `DynamicSystems:-StaircaseTransformation` when the staircase method is specified. So here too you could issue `showstat(DynamicSystems::StaircaseTransformation)` to see the source of that internal (local) routine. Or you could `trace` that routine as well.

As a general rule, you can refer to `exports` of a module or package using the `:-` notation. And you can pass such names to `trace` and `showstat` using the `::` notation instead of `:-`, unless you have first set `kernelopts(opaquemodules=false)`. If an inner submodule member has more than one `:-` in its name then you'd have to use round-bracket delimiters to refer to it with the `::` syntax. Sorry, that that's not so easy to express.

Comment: I see. Thank you so WWmuch! You explaind alot. BTW do you happen to know any system alike maple that would show good, detailed steps on solving Dynamic Systems?